# Cannot find module '@microsoft/gulp-core-build-serve'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am getting following stack trace while executing `gulp package-solution`.

I can't create package due to this error.

```
>gulp package-solution
{ Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/gulp-core-build-serve'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\gulpfile.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
[14:57:51] Error - Unknown
 Cannot find module '@microsoft/gulp-core-build-serve'
[14:57:52] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[14:57:52] Project weather version: 0.0.1
[14:57:52] Build tools version: 2.5.3
[14:57:52] Node version: v8.0.0
[14:57:52] Total duration: 2.72 s
[14:57:52] Task errors: 2
```

Which tools I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules folder and restoring dependencies using the `npm install` command?

Comment: No.I haven't tried that but I have uninstalled node v8.0 and installed v6.10.3.

Comment: Try reinstalling dependencies by removing the node_modules folder and running the `npm install` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error log, it seems you are using the incorrect version of `Node`.

According to this - [Set up your SharePoint client-side web part development environment](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment.md), you need to install the LTS version of Node. The latest LTS version is `v6.10.3`.

I would suggest that you uninstall the current Node js installation and then reinstall with the LTS version and then check.

Download link - [Latest LTS Version: v6.10.3](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: again getting same error : Cannot find module '@microsoft/gulp-core-build-serve'

Comment: can you create a new sample project and check ?